# Cloudera Hadoop - Node list / roles

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

We are a growing company, with approximately 60 Cloudera Hadoop nodes.  We are attempting to put better monitoring controls in place, and I was wondering is there a way we can export a list of nodes, list the individual roles that are associated with each?  I can display them individually in Clouder manager, but I'm looking for more of an export function.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Try yarn rmadmin -showLabels

Answer (score 0):

You can [export a JSON cluster template](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/07/new-in-cloudera-manager-5-7-cluster-templates/) with the Cloudera Manager API from version 5.7. The relevant API call would be `GET {CMhost}/api/v12/clusters/{clusterName}/export` ([from here](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v12/path__clusters_-clusterName-_export.html))